# Debian 10 KDE - ... update microcode to version: 0x20 (or later)

Tags: debian, bios, intel, firmware, pci

So `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode` tells me that the package `intel-microcode` is not available, but referenced in another package. This can mean that it's missing, that it has been replaced or that it's only available through another source. It also tells me that there doesn't exist any installation candidate for the package `intel-microcode`. So I run `sudo dmesg | grep microcode` and it says

```
[    0.137753] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version 0x20 (or later) 
[    0.378605] SRBDS: Vulnerable: no microcode
[    0.378606] MDS: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode
[    3.290134] microcode: sig=0x40651, pf=0x40, revision=0x1c
[    3.290194] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```

The first line of which I get at every system boot. I also don't know how to update a BIOS, if you might suggest that. I suppose the overall issue is due or corelated to  the `iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode` firmware missing in order for my PCI-WiFi to work properly, even though I extracted the `.tgz` contents into `/lib/firmware`. But I have no idea how to go on about this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to install `intel-microcode`, you need to enable the non-free repositories ([non-free in the “free as in freedom” sense](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive#the-non-free-archive-area)):

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/buster[^ ]* main$/& contrib non-free/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
```

This will allow you to install `intel-microcode`.